# Syntax for diagonal variance-covariance matrix for non-linear mixed effects model in nlme

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I am analysing routinely collected substance use data during the first 12 months' of treatment in a large sample of outpatients attending drug and alcohol treatment services. I am interested in whether differing levels of methamphetamine use (no use, low use, and high use) at the outset of treatment predicts different levels after a year in treatment, but the data is very irregular, with different clients measured at different times and different *numbers* of times during their year of treatment.

The data for the high and low use group seem to suggest that drug use at outset reduces during the first 3 months of treatment and then asymptotes. Hence I thought I would try a non-linear exponential decay model.

I started with the following nonlinear generalised least squares model using the `gnls()` function in the `nlme` package:

```
fitExp <- gnls(outcome ~ C*exp(-k*yearsFromStart),
               params = list(C ~ atsBase_fac, k ~ atsBase_fac),
               data = dfNL,
               start = list(C = c(nsC[1], lsC[1], hsC[1]),
                            k = c(nsC[2], lsC[2], hsC[2])),
               weights = varExp(-0.8, form = ~ yearsFromStart),
               control = gnlsControl(nlsTol = 0.1))
```

where `outcome` is number of days of drug use in the 28 days previous to measurement, `atsBase_fac` is a three-level categorical predictor indicating level of amphetamine use at baseline (`noUse`, `lowUse`, and `highUse`), `yearsFromStart` is a continuous predictor indicating time from start of treatment in years (baseline = 0, max - 1), `C` is a parameter indicating initial level of drug use, and `k` is the rate of decay in drug use. The starting values of `C` and `k` are taken from `nls` models estimating these parameters for each group. These are the results of that model

```
Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
  Model: outcome ~ C * exp(-k * yearsFromStart) 
  Data: dfNL 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  27672.17 27725.29 -13828.08

Variance function:
 Structure: Exponential of variance covariate
 Formula: ~yearsFromStart 
 Parameter estimates:
    expon 
0.7927517 

Coefficients:
                      Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
C.(Intercept)      0.130410 0.0411728  3.16738  0.0015
C.atsBase_faclow   3.409828 0.1249553 27.28839  0.0000
C.atsBase_fachigh 20.574833 0.3122500 65.89218  0.0000
k.(Intercept)     -1.667870 0.5841222 -2.85534  0.0043
k.atsBase_faclow   2.481850 0.6110666  4.06150  0.0000
k.atsBase_fachigh  9.485155 0.7175471 13.21886  0.0000
```

So it looks as if there are differences between groups in initial rate of drug use and in rate of reduction in drug use. I would like to go a step further and fit a nonlinear mixed effects model.I tried consulting Pinhiero and Bates' book accompanying the nlme package but the only models I could find that used irregular, sparse data like mine used a self-starting function, and my model does not do that.

I tried to adapt the `gnls()` model to `nlme` like so:

```
fitNLME <- nlme(model = outcome ~ C*exp(-k*yearsFromStart),
                data = dfNL,
                fixed = list(C ~ atsBase_fac, k ~ atsBase_fac),
                random = pdDiag(yearsFromStart ~ id),
                groups = ~ id,
                start = list(fixed = c(nsC[1], lsC[1], hsC[1], nsC[2], lsC[2], hsC[2])),
                weights = varExp(-0.8, form = ~ yearsFromStart),
                control = nlmeControl(optim = "optimizer"))
```

bit I keep getting error message, I presume through errors in the syntax specifying the random effects.

**Can anyone give me some tips on how the syntax for the random effects works in** `nlme`**?**

The only dataset in Pinhiero and Bates that resembled mine used a diagonal variance-covariance matrix. Can anyone filled me in on the syntax of this `nlme` function, or suggest a better one?

p.s. I wish I could provide a reproducible example but coming up with synthetic data that re-creates the same errors is way beyond my skills.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem but I feel `random = pdDiag(yearsFromStart ~ 1)` because `id` be in group.